# making a discord bot say the rules when aksed

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

hello I am trying to code a Discord bot, I am trying to make it so that if someone says `$rules` the rules will be sent, I can't send the code because I have a problem with posting something on this website, I have searched a lot on the internet but I can not find anything
edit: I have found out how I can post the code    https://glitch.com/edit/#!/melted-messy-leotard
this is the link to see it

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code - you never close the listener with any brackets.

To fix this you can use this:

```js
let Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "ping") {
        message.channel.send("pong!")
    }

    if(message.content === "embed") {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("this is Emded title")
            .setDescription("this is Embed description")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setFooter("This is embed footer")
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }

    if (message.content.startswith("$rules")) {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first()
        if (!member) message.send("here are the rules, 1. no politics 2. be nice 3. respect others 4. think before you speak 5. no nsfw 6. don't leak personal info 7.don't argue abt opinions, 3 strikes and you're out")
    }

});

client.login("token");
```

Also your line where you do `if(!member)` probably won't do what you want it to do - this will respond if it DMs the bot, if this is what you wanted then it is fine.

If you want to check if the member is in a guild, you can check if they have a common role (such as everyone) using this:

```js
if (!member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === '<role name>')) {
    // member is not in guild
}
```